# Position: Fixed; Not working properly

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I'm just getting started coding and have run into some problems while trying to use position: fixed; in CSS during one of my practice sessions.

This is what I want things to look like (affected area highlighted red):
WHAT I WANT
[image: WHAT I WANT]

I want the red header to be in a fixed position as the user scrolls down the page like on facebook or youtube. I have applied a z-index: 1; (as currently it is the only indexed item on the page) and a position: fixed;. This results in the header being fixed and scrolling as I want but it fixes it 40-50px down from the top of the page which is not what i want! See image here:

WHAT I GET
[image: WHAT I GET]

Obviously I'm missing something obvious but I'm tearing my hair out trying to find it!

Can anyone help?

See my HTML and CSS code below.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
}

#container {
}

#header {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 10;
}

#video {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 650px;
 height: 400px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#description {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 650px;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#comments {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 650px;
 height: 400px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 120px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#rightadbox {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 350px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 800px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#right {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 350px;
 height: 1000px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 800px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
}
#footer {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <!--PUT CSS LINK HERE-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PracticeHTMLCSS.css"/>
  <title>Practice HTML</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
   </div>
   <div id="video">
   </div>
   <div id="description">
   </div>
   <div id="comments">
   </div>
   <div id="rightadbox">
   </div>
   <div id="right">
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If my answer works, Accept my answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `top: 0;` To your header id in the css file. As your header does not know where to be placed. This will make the distance from the header to the top of your page zero, hence solving your issue

```
#header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0; <-- 
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. A mix of all your answers resulted in what I wanted. There was then a further issue where my right column was still behind the header when my left column wasn't, but I've fixed that with margins.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify where you want the div to be on the page. Add `top: 0px;` to your CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Edit `0px` accordingly until you find that it is in the place you wish.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. A mix of all your answers resulted in what I wanted. There was then a further issue where my right column was still behind the header when my left column wasn't, but I've fixed that with margins.

Comment: You could always change the `z-index` value? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
#header{
   top:0
}
```

to your css

and you should also add a `padding-top:50px;` to your body element to prevent hiding elements behind the fixed header

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. A mix of all your answers resulted in what I wanted. There was then a further issue where my right column was still behind the header when my left column wasn't, but I've fixed that with margins.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you should have a container for everything else excluding header, this is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <!--PUT CSS LINK HERE-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PracticeHTMLCSS.css"/>
  <title>Practice HTML</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">
   </div>
   
            <div id="sitebody"><!-- body container -->
            <div id="video">
   </div>
   <div id="description">
   </div>
   <div id="comments">
   </div>
   <div id="rightadbox">
   </div>
   <div id="right">
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
            </div><!-- // END body container -->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The new container should have a space at the top, as height as your header, and the #header must have "top:0;" in order to work, so you could try with this:

```css
#sitebody {
 position:relative;
    margin-top:70px; /** you can change this **/
}


#header {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0; /*** POSITION FIXED INTRUCTIONS ***/
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks all. A mix of all your answers resulted in what I wanted. There was then a further issue where my right column was still behind the header when my left column wasn't, but I've fixed that with margins.

Comment: Great. I suggest you to use Chrome Inspect tool. It's usefull to visualize your css and save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

yes I check your code , you only need to replace this header css code

```
#header {
background-color: red;
width: 100%;
height:100px;
position: fixed;
top:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below lines fixed my issue:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
z-index: 10;
```